# Combining multiple (almost) identical methods with different views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my current MVC Project, I have a controller with the following method:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string answer)
    {
        using (S3WEntities1 ent = new S3WEntities1())
        {
            afqList.Question = ent.Questions.Where(w => w.QuQuestionId == 1).Select(s => s.QuQuestion).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            afqList.Answers = ent.Answers.Where(w => w.AnsQuestionId == 1).Select(s => s.AnsAnswer).ToList();
        }

        return View(afqList);
    }
```

However, this method is repeated 5 times, all with the only difference being that the number in `(w => w.QuQuestionId == x)` and `(w => w.AnsQuestionId == x)` changes, as well as having 5 different, although still similar, views for each method. How would I make this code a **lot** better than having 5 almost identical methods, but all still having different views? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I should also mention that in each of these methods, the corresponding view has a

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Question3", "ControllerName", "FormMethod.Post))
```

and so need to call different methods based on which one comes next and is stated in the views.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the number with x which will be passed as parameter

```
 public ActionResult Index(string answer, int x)
    {
        using (S3WEntities1 ent = new S3WEntities1())
        {
            afqList.Question = ent.Questions.Where(w => w.QuQuestionId == x).Select(s => s.QuQuestion).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            afqList.Answers = ent.Answers.Where(w => w.AnsQuestionId == x).Select(s => s.AnsAnswer).ToList();
        }

        return View(afqList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First add to your model:

```
public string NextQuestion { get; set; }
```

Then you can use it in your action and view:

```
public ActionResult Index(string answer, int questionId)
    {
        using (S3WEntities1 ent = new S3WEntities1())
        {
            afqList.Question = ent.Questions.Where(w => w.QuQuestionId == questionId).Select(s => s.QuQuestion).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            afqList.Answers = ent.Answers.Where(w => w.AnsQuestionId == questionId).Select(s => s.AnsAnswer).ToList();
        }

        afqList.NextQuestion = string.Format("Question{0}", questionId + 1);

        return View(afqList);
    }
```

Now in the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(afqList.NextQuestion, "ControllerName", "FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: interesting... but you could just handle the logic in the view... but like the idea

Comment: My bad, thought he wanted different views, but same method. So I kinda combined.

Comment: @SynerCoder Yup, I do. And I think this is very close to what I need. Question tho, is there anyway of changing which method is called next for the next method to be called in the view? (My latest edit to my question might explain this better)

Comment: it would still be better to have the logic in 1 view... no need to have x views for the same thing...

Comment: @DannyGoodall changed my answer to reflect your question better

Comment: @SynerCoder This is looking very helpful currently. Gonna try it out now. Thanks!